# Forking mainnet and modifying its state on frontend

Tags: frontend, foundry

I would like to simulate a contract interaction in a frontend application but in order to do so I need to impersonate an address and mint a certain amount of ERC20 to that address. This is fairly straightforward to do with frameworks like Foundry or Hardhat.

Is there some way how to get this functionality on frontend? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look into [hardhat's impersonate account](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/reference/). Basically `hardhat_impersonateAccount` Hardhat Network allows you to send transactions impersonating specific account and contract addresses.

To impersonate an account use the this method, passing the address to impersonate as its parameter:

```
await hre.network.provider.request({
  method: "hardhat_impersonateAccount",
  params: ["0x364d6D0333432C3Ac016Ca832fb8594A8cE43Ca6"],
});
```

If you are using hardhat-ethers (opens new window), call `getSigner` after impersonating the account:

```
const signer = await ethers.getSigner("0x364d6D0333432C3Ac016Ca832fb8594A8cE43Ca6")
signer.sendTransaction(...)
```

Call `hardhat_stopImpersonatingAccount` to stop impersonating.

Comment: I am aware of this. I just wonder whether I can spin up hardhat network on frontend or whether it's designed only for nodejs environment. Thanks

Comment: Yeah you can use hardhat for the front end

Comment: I was not aware of that. Thank you for pointing that out